# Intermittent reponse from http.post in angular

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a couple of problems and wondered if anyone has had anything similar, I have a service with the following code:

```
public authenticate(username: string, password: string) {
  return this.http
    .post<any>('/api/login/', { username, password }, { observe: 'response' })
    .pipe(tap(response => (this.token = response.headers.get('authorization'))));
}
```

This normally works absolutely fine however very rarely, it wont make the call. It doesn't show up in the network tab or anything, it calls the function and just stops there.

Hope someone can help with this,

Thanks

Comment: Can't really help unless we can replicate the issue or there are certain criteria for which this happens. Are the requests getting cancelled?

Comment: @NicholasK it doesn't do anything, I can't see the requests happening and any subscriptions don't happen, no matter if they are for the response or the error